# ¿Cómo modificar nodo en documento XML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Necesito modificar un nodo de un documento XML, actualmente el documento es algo así (No lo muestro todo porque es muy extenso, solo la parte que nos interesa), lo importante es encontrar el elemento  `**<ds:Transforms>**` y modificarlo para que se vea como muestro más abajo en el post

```
<FacturaElectronica>
<ds:Signature Id="Signature-707e5067-a3d2-42bf-904a-f062e903011d" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
           <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
           -<ds:Reference Id="Reference-95c7c8eb-4158-4ba8-b3c9-f9aae7383e9d" URI="">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                      <ds:DigestMethodAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>9tXsKkXmAQ30gdYPDHAPLHn3dahuTKYrkMsorEgNMas=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
.
.
.
</FacturaElectronica>
```

Entonces ese elemento debería quedar de esta forma:

```
<ds:Transforms>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
        <ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>
    </ds:Transform>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
```

Mi codigo (No funciona en Transforms)

```
private string ModificarTransForm(string path)
    {
        string result = "";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
        try
        {
           string uri = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";

            XmlElement XPath = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ds", "XPath", uri);
            XPath.InnerText = "//. | //@* | //namespace::*";

            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsManager.AddNamespace("ds", uri);
            XmlNode Transform = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ds:Transform", nsManager);
            if (Transform != null)
            {
                Transform.AppendChild(XPath);
            }
            xmlDoc.Save(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { result = ex.ToString(); }
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Son exactamente los mismos pasos que lo que te respondí en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131654/127

Comment: Hola Mariano...Edite mi post para que veas el codigo que utiliizo y no me esta funcionando para este caso

Comment: @Efrain estás buscando seleccionar el nodo `xades:Transforms` que no existe, debería ser `ds:Transforms`... Código funcionando -> http://rextester.com/LMFDG42724

Comment: Edite el post en el codigo que utilizo por que aunque cambie el prefijo aun no funciona

Comment: Mariano ...Listo ahora si funciono ...estaba mal la variable uri ...Si quieres publica una respuesta para marcarla como valida y ganes reputacion

Comment: @Efrain me alegro! Y gracias, pero realmente creo que es exactamente el mismo concepto que en tu pregunta anterior. Me parece que conviene que la cierres como duplicada.